# Sync Gradle failed : ERROR: For input string: ""

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I don't have any Google services in the Gradle file, but it's still giving me this error `ERROR: For input string: ""`

I didn't add any Firebase SDK or AdMob it's more likely to be related to a malfunction or a bug in the dependencies that I'm not aware of or something that need some update in this regard

Her is the **build.gradle** code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def gitCommits = 'git rev-list --all --count'.execute([], rootDir).text.trim().toInteger()

def timestamp = new Date().getTime()

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.app.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode gitCommits
        versionName "5.0"

        resConfigs "en", "ru", "tr", "uk"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SELFUPDATE_ENABLED", "false"
        buildConfigField "String", "SELFUPDATE_URL", "\"http://randomwebsite.link/v.0.3/get/openmanga/version\""
        buildConfigField "String", "SYNC_URL", "\"http://random.random.com/api/v1\""
        buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", "${timestamp}L"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.jks")
            storePassword "develop"
            keyAlias "develop"
            keyPassword "develop"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "OpenManga-v${defaultConfig.versionName}")
            resValue "string", "app_name", "OpenManga"
        }

        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix="a"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue "string", "app_name", "OpenManga Debug"
        }

        fdroid {
            initWith release
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SELFUPDATE_ENABLED", "false"
            versionNameSuffix="-fdroid"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }
}

ext {
    supportLib = '28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.3.0'
    implementation 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:2.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher-okhttp3:2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

it's more likely that I'm blind or something but I would love some help now I understand that I probably missed something

How can I fix that? What is wrong?

Comment: Hey Mike, welcome to SO! According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, the question should have the shortest code possible. Can you narrow down the problem to a certain section of your file so that it's easier for potential answerers to debug? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where is the section that contains the error

Comment: @MikeLinkerr the section that contains the error is versionCode gitCommits. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution as no one didn't see it

So what I did it that I removed two lines of codes in the `build.gradle` :

> `def gitCommits = 'git rev-list --all --count'.execute([],`
>
> `versionCode gitCommits`

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: For input string: ""

You are trying to convert a String into an Integer but as the variable doesn't contain valid data it's throwing the error.

This line

```
def gitCommits = 'git rev-list --all --count'.execute([], rootDir).text.trim().toInteger()
```

doesn't return an Integer and `versionCode` (since you are using  `versionCode gitCommits`) expects an `Integer` value.